Statsmodels OLS regression giving wrong results
I have the following model that I ran using     statsmodels.formula.api:
result=smf.ols('post_sls ~ test + pre_sls', data=df).fit().summary() 
Post_sls and pre_sls are floats, test is an integer taking a value of 0 or 1.
I am getting the following output:




coef
std err
t
P>t




Intercept
4.2039
0.137
30.791
0.000


test
0.1060
0.137
0.775
0.439


pre_sls
0.0978
0.000
737.305
0.000



Statsmodels output
The values for intercept and test coefficients are wrong, as I keep getting different results using lm in R, linear model in sklearn and by calculating the coefficients manually.
R code and output:
model <- lm(post_sls ~ test + pre_sls, data = df)
result <- summary(model)




coef
std err
t
P>t




Intercept
4.1283
0.137
30.237
0.000


test
0.1819
0.137
1.329
0.184


pre_sls
0.0978
0.000
737.306
0.000



R output
Sklearn code and output:
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X = df[['test', 'pre_sls']]
y = df['post_sls']
model = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
print(f'Intercept: {model.intercept_}')
print(f'Coefficients: {model.coef_}')
print(f'R^2: {model.score(X, y)}')
Output
Intercept: 4.128324040176458
Coefficients: [0.18193744 0.0978311 ]
R^2: 0.06522976694251192
Manual calculation code and output:
import patsy
formula = 'post_sls ~ test + pre_sls'
y, X = patsy.dmatrices(formula, df)
beta = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ (X.T @ y)
print(beta)
Output
[[4.12832404]
 [0.18193744]
 [0.0978311 ]]
As you can see, all used methods deliver the same coefficients, except for the statsmodels. The interesting thing is that the sum of the intercept coefficient and the test coefficient is the same across models, but somehow statsmodels overestimate the intercept and underestimate the test coefficient.
Does anyone have an idea of what is going wrong here?
Thanks,
Alona

summary in statsmodels shows the condition number and a warning for multicollinearity. My guess is that test is nearly constant or has tiny variance/mean ratio. In this case intercept and parameter for test are not separately identified except for numerical noise or if algorithm chooses a specific solution among the multiplicity of solutions.

This explanation makes sense as I have 40K observations where test=0 and 8M with test=1. Are you aware of a way to resolve this?

demeaning test should work. Statsmodels does not do any special handling of the intercept.

another possibility that I think should work and provide better inference is to reverse the dummy variable 0-1. i.e. use test=0 for the majority of the data and test=1 for the few observations in the minority. This way the test parameter would capture only how much the minority differs from the majority and does not have the conflict whether majority effect is in intercept or test. (standard errors will adjust and should be more reliable.)
